# Can't set size of PictureBox to size of screen resolution: "Declaration expected"

Tags: vb.net, winforms, picturebox

In a Windows Forms application, I'm trying to set a PictureBox to the max screen resolution. I attempted to do it using the following code

```
Dim screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
Dim screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
Dim ratio = width / height
Dim newWidth = Width
Dim newHeight = Height / ratio
PictureBox1.size = New Size(newWidth, newHeight)
```

but it errors out with "Declaration expected" on line 6. I placed the PictureBox with Visual Basic's designer in VS 2015 Express.

Comment: What is line seven?  Where does width and height come from?  Why are you ignoring screenWidth and screenHeight?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant line 6. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

Check the PictureBox name generated by yhe VS designer, ensure it is really PictureBox1.

Check the namespace where your designer generates PictureBox1, ensure it matches with the namespace of the class where you use PictureBox1

That being said, I notice some other potential errors in your code too. Note that you must declare a variable before using it. These lines:

```
Dim screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
Dim screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
Dim ratio = width / height
Dim newWidth = Width
Dim newHeight = Height / ratio
```

Violates it:

1. Naturally, screenWidth and screenHeight are declared, but never used

Try to change your variable names where they are used before they are declared (such that they are all consistently used).

Comment: Sorry! I think the namespace is the issue. How would I fix the namespace though?

Comment: Make sure the namespace are the same.

Comment: Visual Basic variables are **not** case sensitive. You are thinking of C#. One of the main things I see is that he is Dimming his variables without stating the Type using As. He really should be putting Option Strict On

Comment: @MarkHall `Dim x = 1` it is equivalent to `var x = 1;` and it doesn't need declaring type strictly. The only thing which is needed to make dim work this way is `Option Infer On` which is on by default; in project properties, compile tab.

Comment: @MarkHall You can keep option infer on but also turn on option strict. This way if you write `Dim x = 1` then if you write `x = "test"` you will receive a compile time error: *Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Integer'.* this way, it works similar C#

Comment: @MarkHall These options are available, and surely we are free to choose :)

Comment: So if I added something in the designer, how would I reference it in the code? It's clearly not in the same namespace, so what should I do?

Comment: @r3muxd If you add something in the designer it will be in the same namespace as Form you placed it on, If you are trying to reference it from another form you will need to pass a reference to the form that contains the control to the form that you are trying to manipulate it with. Without seeing more of your code it is hard to know what your problem is.